# Refresh long term page access facebook tokens via CLI

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I'm storing long term page access facebook tokens for pages on my application for use - however I need to know if theres a way to refresh or extend these page tokens via a cron job. At the moment the only way I think this can be accomplished is via the user flow of authenticating via facebook.

Can't it be done such that I can have a cron job that every week goes through the facebook tokens I'm storing in my database and make a CURL request to retrieve an updated token and store that?

Comment: Long term page access tokens are valid forever. No reason to renew them

Comment: @WizKid: Almost a year now, but your comment is very incorrect... Long-lived token have a validity period of ~2 months.

Comment: Long term page access tokens are valid forever. Long lived user access tokens are valid for 2 months